# UILabel looks pixelated with shadow

Tags: swift, swift3

You can see in the picture, that the label inside of the view with the shadow looks pixelated (also the UIButton) and the other one outside this shadow UIView looks normal. How can I remove this pixelated effect?

[image: The pixelated label and button]

Thanks for your awnsers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you **have not set** `shouldRasterize` property; **if so, then try unsetting** it.
From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410905-shouldrasterize):

> **should​Rasterize**
>   *A Boolean that indicates whether the layer is
>   rendered as a bitmap before compositing*.

which may have turned your label to pixelated.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Yeah that's it! Thank You!